# insert multiple with same id

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a invoice in which there are different products and every product has their own specific quantity and weight. Suppose there are 10 products. i want to insert all product with their own quantity and weight in database(mysql using php) against same invoice id. how to do that. Invoice form look like:

```
INVOICE ID__________                   DATE__________#
PRODUCT1_________           QUANTITY (of product 1)___________      Weight(1)_________
PRODUCT2_________           QUANTITY (of product 2)___________      Weight(2)__________
PRODUCT3_________           QUANTITY (of product 3)___________      Weight(3)__________
PRODUCT4________            QUANTITY (of product 4)___________      Weight(4)__________
PRODUCT5________            QUANTITY (of product 5)___________      Weight(5)___________
```

I have submit button when i submit it i  want to insert it into database with same invioce number.Hope you people understand my problem.

Comment: Set the invoice ID up as a foreign key in your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not intended as an answer per se, merely a suggested approach that I have used myself.

This approach assumes you will not have more than 20 or 30 products per invoice. I also assume you have a table called "invoices".

Create one field in the invoices table structure for the product items on your invoice (eg. "prods"). Make it large enough to hold all the text you will need for > 30 items.

Store each product/quantity/weight as a delimited string, and upon retrieval break the string back into its component items.

Example:

```
Product           Qty   Weight
Grommits           5    30g
Widgets           22    5.25g
Things like this   3    0.75g
```

Stored string:

```
Grommits~5~30g|Widgets~22~5.25g|Things like this~3~0.75g
```

Comment: There are a couple of issues with doing it this way - firstly, it's a lot trickier to edit the order, because you're working with a string (read it from DB / deserialise / make changes / serialize / write back), whereas with a normalized data structure, you can update it directly. Secondly - what happens when you get an order that's too large for the column you've allocated?

Comment: That said - this approach does work, but you just need to make sure that you know its limitations, too.